# Joining 3 tables in Sqlite and not receiving expected output

Tags: sql, sqlite

I understand similar question have been posted, however my issue isn't an error rather the lack of the desired result. I'm trying to join 3 tables each with 10,000 observations and combine them in the one table, however when i use inner join the observations reduce to little over 4000. I understand that INNER JOIN is essentially an intersection but I'm expecting 10,000 observations and based on my code I don't see how that is occurring. Here is my code:

SELECT *
FROM Characteristics

INNER JOIN Prices ON Prices.pid = Characteristics.pid

INNER JOIN Locations ON Locations.tid = Characteristics.tid

;

**CHARACTERISTICS**

||Property_Id||     ||Beds||    ||Baths||      ||Type_ID||

**PRICES**

||Price||       ||Year||        ||Property_ID||

**LOCATIONS**

||Type_ID||      ||X coord||    ||Y coord||

Those are representative of the tables I didn't include numbers because of formatting issues but as you can imagine the number contained in Property_id and Type_id are the same for all columns regardless of table, what i would like is one table with each of the respective columns containing 10,000 rows, i've checked for NA values on R and they're all of the same length.

Comment: This is occurig because you are using `inner join`.

Comment: how do i avoid using it, if the tables have overlapping entries?

Comment: You should provide a representative subset of data for all three tables, along with the expected results so we can look into it.

Comment: please see my edit

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep all `characteristics` -- even when there are no matches in the other tables -- then use `left join`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Characteristics c LEFT JOIN
     Prices p
     ON p.pid = c.pid LEFT JOIN
     Locations l
     ON l.tid = c.tid;
```